# Saving related objects in API Platform

Tags: symfony4, api-platform.com

I am new to API Platform and `Symfony 4`, I have a situation where we have 3 entity related to each other: `User`, `Jobseeker`, `JobseekerLocation` so when we need add register new Jobseeker can we make entry in related table automatically? Some kind of triggering.

Or we should make 3 API call to reach and save the data?

Comment: You should take a look at ['stored procedures in mysql'](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-stored-procedure-tutorial.aspx). 
Put simply, a Stored Procedure ("SP") is a procedure (written in SQL and other control statements) stored in a database which can be called by the database engine and connected programming languages

Comment: Thanks Vijay for the quick replay , I was looking for solution from API platform .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `@Groups()`

https://api-platform.com/docs/core/serialization/

```
/**
 * @ApiResource()
 */ 
class User {
    /**
    * @Groups({"registration"})
    * @ORM\ManyToOne/OneToOne(...)
     */
    private $jobSeeker;
}


/**
 * @ApiResource()
 */ 
class JobSeeker {
    /**
    * @Groups({"registration"})
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(...)
     */
    private $jobSeekerLocation;
}

/**
 * @ApiResource()
 */ 
class JobSeekerLocation {

    /**
    * @Groups({"registration"})
    * @ORM\Column(...)
     */
    private $city;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer its working , But I have an issue with validation of email field (  * @UniqueEntity("email",message="That email is already registered") ).
while posting duplicate email its not showing this message .Its showing mysql error message.
Thanks.