# API Platform POST related objects

Tags: symfony4, api-platform.com

I'm trying to post 3 related objects to my API using this body :

```
{
    "poi": {
        "address": {
            "name" : "this is a name"
        }
    },
    "title": "Mr",
    "firstname": "Jon",
    "lastname": "Doe"
}
```

I'm getting this error

> "hydra:description": "An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT
>   INTO address (name) VALUES (?)' with params
>   [null]:\n\nSQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048
>   Column 'name' cannot be null"

the fact that my code got to the point where it tries to insert into the address database means that my objects are related correctly (I guess...) using `@Groups`...might be something wrong with the json format ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Similar question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53867870/saving-related-objects-in-api-platform/53869358#53869358

Comment: @GonZOO not really...I'm using `@Groups` already, my problem is with the format of the body actually.

Comment: Are you use the same `@Groups` in the Address Entity as in the Poi? 
Please copy yours Entities files.

Comment: @GonZOO please check my other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55753672/