# API Platform model attributes are readOnly

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

I'm struggling with this strange behavior with my API: some of the attributes are set to `readOnly: true`.

**EDIT: This is how my entities are defined**

```
/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *     normalizationContext={"groups"={"read_partenaire"}},
 *     denormalizationContext={"groups"={"write_partenaire"}}
 * )
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ProfessionnelRepository")
 * @ApiFilter(SearchFilter::class, properties={"nom": "partial", "id": "exact"})
 */

class Professionnel
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Groups({"read_partenaire"})
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Partenaire", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     * @Groups({"read_partenaire","write_partenaire"})
     *
     */
    private $partenaire;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=4)
     * @Groups({"read_partenaire","write_partenaire"})
     *
     */
    private $civilite;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     * @Groups({"read_partenaire","write_partenaire"})
     *
     */
    private $nom;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     * @Groups({"read_partenaire","write_partenaire"})
     *
     */
    private $prenom;
```

The second entity :

```
/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *     normalizationContext={"groups"={"read_partenaire"}},
 *     denormalizationContext={"groups"={"write_partenaire"}}
 * )
 * @ApiFilter(SearchFilter::class, properties={"id": "exact"})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\PartenaireRepository")
 */
class Partenaire
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Groups({"read_partenaire"})
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Ban", inversedBy="partenaires", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     * @Groups({"read_partenaire","write_partenaire"})

     */
    private $ban;
```

The third entity:

```
/**
 * @ApiResource()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\BanRepository")
 */
class Ban
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Groups({"read_partenaire"})
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Groups({"read_partenaire","write_partenaire"})
     *
     */
    private $nom_voie;
```

To sum it up, my `Professionnel` entity is nested to `Partenaire` which is nested to `Ban`. So by creating a new `Professionnel` a new `Partenaire` and `Ban` should be created as well.

Please keep in mind that all the properties of my 3 entities have `get` and `set` functions (except id's of course)...but for some reason, the property `nom_voie` of my third entity is set to readOnly (and because of that, the insert of all the entities fail...)
[image: Here is the entity documentation I get]

I'm not sure how exactly this two-level nesting should be expressed using `Groups` I tried many combinations but no luck...

Comment: First things first: have you tried clearing the cache? `docker-compose exec php app/console cache:clear`

Answer (score 2):

if you automatically generated  getter and setter methods  for $nom_voie attribute with "php bin/console make:entity" that probably would be  getNomVoie() and setNomVoie() .

Api platform is looking for a setter method to decide if attribute is readonly and cannot associate **$nom_voie** with **setNomVoie**. Either rename attribute in camelCase format ($nomVoie)  or rename the setter method to setNom_voie()

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle readonly attributes, i think you can use normalization/denormalization context instead of "getter/ no setter"

```
Class Address {

 //...  


 /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @Groups({"read", "write"})
 */
private $numero;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @Groups({"read"})
 */
private $code_insee;


public function getNumero(): ?int
{
    return $this->numero;
}

public function setNumero(int $numero): self
{
    $this->numero = $numero;

    return $this;
}
public function getCodeInsee(): ?int
{
    return $this->code_insee;
}

public function setCodeInsee(int $code_insee): self
{
    $this->code_insee = $code_insee;

    return $this;
   }
}
```

and

```
services:
    # ...

resource.Address:
    parent:    "api.resource"
    arguments: [ "AppBundle\Entity\Address" ]
    calls:
        -      method:    "initNormalizationContext"
               arguments: [ { groups: [ "read" ] } ]
        -      method:    "initDenormalizationContext"
               arguments: [ { groups: [ "write" ] } ]
    tags:      [ { name: "api.resource" } ]
```

Comment: Sorry that wasn't clear in my question but Im indeed using normalization/denormalization to read/write (check updated question)...what I'm trying to figure out is why with the same code some attributes are readOnly and some are not.

Answer (score 0):

You have to update your entity as follow, you cant have the same group name for normalization and denormalization, now for properties that you need to submit and read its value later add the both groups to it {"ban_read", "ban_write"}, for Id for example only "ban_read" needed because you will not submit id value.

```
 * @ApiResource(
 *     normalizationContext={"groups"={"ban_read"}, "swagger_definition_name": "read"},
 *     denormalizationContext={"groups"={"ban_write"}, "swagger_definition_name": "write"}
 * )
 */ 
Class Address {
     //...  


     /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Groups({"ban_read"})
     */
    private $numero;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Groups({"ban_write","ban_read"})
     */
    private $code_insee;

   //here you can see they both have identical getter and setter :

    public function getNumero(): ?int
    {
        return $this->numero;
    }

    public function setNumero(int $numero): self
    {
        $this->numero = $numero;

        return $this;
    }
    public function getCodeInsee(): ?int
    {
        return $this->code_insee;
    }

    public function setCodeInsee(int $code_insee): self
    {
        $this->code_insee = $code_insee;

        return $this;
       }
    }
```

**UPDATE:**
Create unique groups for each entity for example read_ban, write_ban then in the Professionnel entity update the denormalizationContext to include all other groups.

```
denormalizationContext={"groups"={"write_professionnel","write_partenaire", "write_ban"}}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that the group names should be different. but in my case, that's not the issue because I still have attributes on readOnly when actually they should not...please check updated question.

Comment: Tried that too: same effect...some attributes are still read only when I try to `POST` from the parent entity (`GET` seems to work) here is an example : `numero integer
code_insee integer
readOnly: true` ... both attributes `numero`and `code_insee`have getters and setters and the same annotations..     `* @Groups({"read_partenaire","write_partenaire"})` `public function setNumero(int $numero): self
    {
        $this->numero = $numero;

        return $this;
    }`
seems like a bug on Api Platform to me...